# Почему у переменной значения, которых не должно быть?

Tags: массивы, delphi-7

Сама задача такова: Найти максимальный элемент двумерного массива.

Сразу говорю на PascalABC код прекрасно работает. Вот код на Delphi:

Так вот, единственная проблема в том что Imax=1242752, я незнаю почему у нее такие значения

```
procedure Mass1();
var i,j: byte;
var a: TMatrix; // TMatrix = array [1..n,1..n] of integer;
var Imax: integer;
begin
  Imax := a[1,1]; // Iznachalno Imax=a[1,1]
  Form1.Label1.Caption := '';
  Randomize;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    for j := 1 to n do
    begin
      a[i,j] := random(100);
      if Imax < a[i,j] then Imax := a[i,j];
      Form1.Label1.Caption := Form1.Label1.Caption + IntToStr(a[i,j]) + ' ';
    end;
    Form1.Label1.Caption := Form1.Label1.Caption + #13;
  end;
  Form1.Label2.Caption := 'Max = ' + IntToStr(Imax); // Pochemyto Imax=1242752 
end;
```

Comment: `Imax:=0;` вместо `Imax:=a[1,1];`

Comment: Спасибо,заработало,вопрос:почему в паскале работало и по логике в Delphi 
тоже долженн работать?

Comment: @MBo `a[i,j]:=random(100);`

Comment: @ОсманНиязов Вероятно, в Паскале массивы инициализируются нулями по умолчанию.

Comment: Imax:=0 не всегда будет достаточно - если в массиве могут быть отрицательные элементы, это не сработает. Более универсально - назначить -MaxInt-1 или всё же значение из первой ячейки - но только **после её инициализации**

Comment: `вопрос:почему в паскале работало и по логике в Delphi тоже долженн работать?` могло не работать и в паскале. Ни делфи ни паскаль не несет ответственности за содержимое не инициализированных переменных. И еще один совет - не сравнивайте поведение PascalABC с его каноничными собратьями. Это отдельная "учебная" сборка со множеством нарушений стандарта ЯП Паскаль/Делфи

Answer (score 1):

То, что программа работает, еще не означает, что она работает правильно.

На [официальном сайте PascalABC](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm) сказано:

> Глобальные переменные инициализируются нулевыми значениями. Для локальных переменных это не гарантируется - их надо инициализировать явно.

То, что у вас a[1,1] до инициализации не превосходило все сгенерированные random'ом значения - случайность.

В зависимости от реализации транслятора и действий, которые программа выполняла до этого, вероятность такого поведения может быть очень большой, стремящайся к 100%, но полагаться на то, что так будет всегда - нельзя.

Как правильно сказал MBo нужно инициализировать Imax после Random.

Например, можно заменить фрагмент

```
if Imax < a[i,j] then Imax := a[i,j];
```

на

```
if (i=1) and (j=1) then
  Imax = a[i,j]
else
  if Imax < a[i,j] then Imax := a[i,j];
```